# Doctrine ORM level difference between @UniqueConstraint and @Column(unique=true) options

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

In database level, there is no difference when using one over another option for defining **UNIQUENESS** as shown below. Although `@UniqueConstraint` reads in its documentation "*It only has meaning in the SchemaTool schema generation context*", is there a ORM level difference in between? I mean when we run queries, do things get handled differently?

- [@UniqueConstraint](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#uniqueconstraint)
- [@Column](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-column) (unique=true)

**EXAMPLE - @UniqueConstraint**

CLASS

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(
 *      name="user",
 *      uniqueConstraints={
 *          @ORM\UniqueConstraint(columns={"email"})
 *      }
 * )
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $email;
}
```

DQL

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_8D93D649E7927C74` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**EXAMPLE - @Column - unique=true**

CLASS

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=100, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;
}
```

DQL

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_8D93D649E7927C74` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is basically no difference. Both create a unique key on a column.

But `@UniqueConstraint` has much more possibilities. With `@UniqueConstraint` you can give the key a name or span over multiple columns. The downside is much more to type (not as worse) and the column names must be the column names in the database, not the php property name.

`unique=true` on the `@Column` is the simplest way of creating unique keys on a single column.

While running queries, there is no difference. The ORM doesn't care about unique definitions. Especially on inserts you get a crash from the database about uniqueness violation and not from the ORM. You have to ensure the uniqueness on your own, for example with the unique entity validation in Symfony.

Comment: I faced on a problem if you have a table inheritance it search unique (for example) email only in that type we work with.
In my case, I have `AbstractUser` and `Teacher` and `Student` inheritance with common table `user`. And it doesn't find in a whole table, it finds only with type `teacher`.


To prevent this you can set `entityClass` in `UniqueEntity`. In my case, it's `AbstractUser`, that is, your common (abstract) class.


Hope it helps to someone.

Comment: just FYI, in Symfony, [unique validation docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html)

Comment: Doctrine 2.9 supports both `columns` and `fields` in the [`@UniqueConstraint`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref_uniqueconstraint) so you can define column names *or* PHP class properties.