# Symfony UniqueEntity vs UniqueConstraint vs unique=true

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Can anyone explain what's the conceptual difference between [`@UniqueEntity`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html) validator, [`@UniqueConstraint`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#uniqueconstraint) table annotation and [`unique=true`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#column) option of `@Column` annotation.

I understand that `@UniqueConstraint` adds `UNIQUE` index on database level and `@UniqueEntity` validates on ORM level. So what option shall I use, or do I use all of them?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33196548/doctrine-orm-level-difference-between-uniqueconstraint-and-columnunique-true

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`@UniqueConstraint` and `unique=true` **are part of Doctrine** and do similar thing.

When you set `unique=true` on a particular column, then Doctrine will create a unique key on this column **physically in database**.

`@UniqueConstraint` can be used to create a unique key **in database** on multiple columns (complex unique key). But if you pass a single column, then the result will be exactly the same as using `unique=true` on that field.

`@UniqueEntity` on the other hand is not a part of Doctrine, but **it's a part of Symfony framework**. While options above are used by Doctrine to generate proper schema, this one is just a validator used usually by Symfony Form Component at time of submitting the form.

So to answer your final question - yes, you usually should use both `@UniqueEntity` and one of `@UniqueConstraint` or `unique=true`.

Comment: This elaborates on the differences well. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

As stated in [documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-uniqueconstraint), `@UniqueConstraint` annotation is used for creation of unique constraint on multiple columns, when `unique=true` is used for unique constraint on one column.

`UniqueEntityValidator` exists to show friendly error message and unique database constraint's purpose is to make sure you don't store duplicate data.

So the answer to your question is like this - you should use both database constraint and `@UniqueValidator`.